# Sidebar Transitions

Tags: jquery, css

I did a sidebar menu with transition effect.

the problem is, when I click in the  Icon the sidebar kinda squash sandwiching letters.

```js
$('.fa-bars').on('click', function clickHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.magic-container').toggleClass('closed');
});
```

```css
.sidebar-shrink {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #000;
}
.magic-container.closed .sidebar-left-nav {
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s;
  transition: width 0.3s;
  width: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.magic-container.closed .col-md-10 {
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s;
  transition: width 0.3s;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid magic-container">
    <div class="col-md-2 sidebar-left-nav">
      <div class="sidebar-shrink">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Hello World<i class="pull-right  fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Hello World<i class="pull-right  fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div>
        <h3 class="headline-primary">
         <i class="fa fa-bars pull-left menu-toggle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          Sidebar
          </h3>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

what I trying to archive is this effect REVEAL from here: http://tympanus.net/Development/SidebarTransitions/

I tried translate3d but did not work, someone know how to solve this?

EDIT: I want keep the code and use just css if possible.

thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you want with your code, because your css are not good enough. with your js you just `toggle` closed class so you have to make animate with css.

and it's more easy with css, you have to set first css whatever you want that you reserved animate with toggle your class.

## Example: slide from left with

```
.sidebar-left-nav {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0px, 0px);
  visibility: visible;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.closed .sidebar-left-nav {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  visibility: visible;
}
```

**[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mlimon/r36m4duL/5/)**

Here just set first how to default display your element and after add a class how you want to display that element.

you can also do this with other way like:

```
.sidebar-left-nav {
  left: -100%;
  position:relative;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.closed .sidebar-left-nav {
  left: 0;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

[**jsfiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mlimon/r36m4duL/)

> You said on your post that your "sidebar kinda squash sandwiching
>   letters".

And yes it will be because you want did animate with width, you can't avoid it, if you did animate with width.

If you still want to animate with width, set fixed with px (you can also set dynamic px by jquery) then animate parent element with css width. like:

**[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mlimon/r36m4duL/2/)**

***Q, And more question for you ? what purpose you used part of this code ?***

```
.magic-container.closed .col-md-10 {
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s;
  transition: width 0.3s;
  width: 100%;
}
```

> **Update demos and example - tympanus**

**[Reveal](https://jsfiddle.net/mlimon/r36m4duL/8/)**

**[Push](https://jsfiddle.net/mlimon/r36m4duL/7/)**

> **w3schools examples**

**[w3schools - sidenav_push](https://jsfiddle.net/mlimon/r36m4duL/9/)**

**[Another way w3schools push](https://jsfiddle.net/mlimon/r36m4duL/10/)**

Hope it make sense

Comment: many thanks for this is exactly what I am looking for, but just one thing all your samples the sidebar appears in the top, what I am trying to do is when the sidebar is open push the content to the right, when is close, the content should be push to left like this sample: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_push

Comment: Ok I update my answer. hope it will help to achieve what you have want.

Comment: @Raduken Did you see my demos that I added on my last updated ?

Comment: thanks @mldb, you got the 100 :), just a small question , will be possible after the click  the sidebar-left-nav get removed from DOM?  and main-content get width:100% ? as well if I click again the sidebar-left-nav back to the DOM? that is my last. :0 thank you so much u helped me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

If you animate the sidebar with width property it will collapse the letters. Only way to do it is adding another child div to sidebar and adding sidebar parent overflow-hidden.

But I think this is what you are trying to do :

```js
$('.fa-bars').on('click', function clickHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('body').toggleClass('sidebar-open');
});
```

```css
.product-categories{
  width: 100%;
  float:left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebar-shrink {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #000;
}

.magic-container .sidebar-left-nav {
  width : 300px;
  -webkit-transition : all .3s;
  transition : all .3s;
  position : absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  position: absolute;
  left : 0;
  top : 0;
  height : 100%;
}

body.sidebar-open .sidebar-left-nav {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

body.sidebar-open .col-md-10{
  -webkit-transform: translateX(300px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(300px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(300px);
  -o-transform: translateX(300px);
  transform: translateX(300px);
}

.magic-container .col-md-10 {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid magic-container">
    <div class="col-md-2 sidebar-left-nav">
      <div class="sidebar-shrink">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Hello World<i class="pull-right  fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Hello World<i class="pull-right  fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div>
        <h3 class="headline-primary">
         <i class="fa fa-bars pull-left menu-toggle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          Sidebar
          </h3>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I added static width to sidebar. If you dont want to do that. you need to use window.getComputedStyle(). And add translate value to the col-md-10 via javascript.

Answer (score 2):

I tried something for you hope it will help you  avoid the script i add it because of facing some problem adding fiddle link

```
<script>
var o =document.getElementById("one");
var to =document.getElementById("two");
to.style.display = 'none';

function openNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "150px";
document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "150px";
o.style.display = 'none';
to.style.display = '';
}

function closeNav() {

 document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
 document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
 o.style.display = '';
 to.style.display = 'none';

}

</script>
```

See the **fiddle** below.I saw your effect **"REVEAL"** and try something like that hope it will work for you  or help you to modify more.And yes please add css as your wish I just added by my own you can custom it as yours and also the Js code

[sidebarfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Asifuzzaman/fs96h8m4/)

> If the link breaks again please let me know I will post the whole code

Comment: thanks, but is possible to solve this problem just with css?

Comment: Yes possible by using  "CSS3 Transitions" but you need to write a lot of css code .As you see i didn't change your code just added few javascript its done

Comment: Hi thanks, but even your sample is pushing the icons to the left see: https://jsfiddle.net/fs96h8m4/1/

Answer (score 2):

First you can set `position: absolute` on sidebar to remove it from elements flow and set `z-index: -1` so its under content. Next you can use `width: 100vw` on content so when you use transition content doesn't get affected, and you just create one class that will `transform: translateX()` and toggle it on click.

I also added that dim effect with one pseudo-element that will change its opacity on click, important here is to set `pointer-events: none` so you can click button.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.content').toggleClass('move');
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.content {
  background: white;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  position: absolute;
}
.content:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: black;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.move {
  transform: translateX(200px);
}
.content.move:before {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="content">
  <button>Sidebar</button>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore odio consectetur suscipit, iusto accusantium, aspernatur quia possimus debitis enim similique veniam voluptatem iste soluta, vitae officia quos earum quaerat reprehenderit.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're setting transition and width only to the sidebar, when the sidebar parent has class "closed". All you need is to put transition styles to the sidebar, when parent has no class "closed", like this:

```
 .sidebar-left-nav {
-webkit-transition: width 0.3s;
transition: width 0.3s;
width: 100%; 
}
```

And then put:

```
.magic-container.closed .sidebar-left-nav {
width: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Off course you will need to add more styles for positioning and so on.
Good luck with it!

Comment: thanks for the help, but I could not fix :(, could you edit the jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/uc6yntfL/  , thank you

Comment: Your fiddle stoped working... why don't you just download sources from codropes here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/28/transitions-for-off-canvas-navigations/ 

So that is how you can understand better how it works. All you will need is just remove unnecessary files.

Comment: thanks, but  I am looking to solve my problem using my code.

Comment: Here is something: https://jsfiddle.net/udxve6vy/ 
But your bootstrap grid here is not the best way to make it. I used fixed positioning for that. hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw a CSS only solution into the bunch, I made a version with a checkbox. This way it is fast and works without JavaScript

```css
html,body{
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#sidebarCheckbox{
  display: none;
}
#sidebarCheckbox:checked ~ #main{
  transform: translateX(200px);
}
#sidebar{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  background: #000;
}
#sidebar ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#sidebar a{
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: #05F;
}
#sidebar i.fa-bullhorn{
  float: right;
}
#main{
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}
label[for="sidebarCheckbox"]{
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="sidebarCheckbox" />
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Hello<i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hello<i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <label for="sidebarCheckbox" style="">&#9776; SideBar</label>
</div>
```

I completely dropped the use of Bootstrap, but it's the same principle. There is a checkbox at the top, then comes the `#sidebar` and then the `#main` content. In the main content, there is a label that is linked to the checkbox (with native HTML). When you click it, the checkbox gets checked, which I used in the CSS with

```
#sidebarCheckbox:checked ~ #main{
  transform: translateX(200px);
}
```

It'll go to the main content, and tell it to translate 200px to the right, which is how wide I made the sidebar. You can change this however you want, of course.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Hi Maybe try this code  < -- Update / remove/add DOM element -- >

```js
var clSideBar = $('.magic-container .sidebar-left-nav').clone();
var ctMagic = $('.magic-container');
var sideBarLeft = $('.magic-container .sidebar-left-nav');
var btnBars = $('.magic-container .fa-bars');

sideBarLeft.remove(); // Remove sidebar nav
 
btnBars.on('click', function clickHandler(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   ctMagic.toggleClass('closed');
 
    if(clSideBar && ctMagic.hasClass('closed')) {
         setTimeout(function(){
             clSideBar.remove();
       }, 600);
   } else {
      clSideBar.prependTo(ctMagic);
      clSideBar.addClass('timeout');
       setTimeout(function(){
              clSideBar.removeClass('timeout');
       }, 5);
   }

});
```

```css
.magic-container .sidebar-left-nav {
  width:180px;
  margin-left:0px;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:1;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  padding: 0;
  height:100%;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
  transition: width 0.5s;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.magic-container .sidebar-left-nav.timeout {
  width:0px;
}
.magic-container .cont-main {
  margin-left:180px;
  -webkit-transition: margin-left 0.5s;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s;
}
 
.magic-container.closed .sidebar-left-nav {
  width: 0px;
}
.magic-container.closed .cont-main {
  margin-left:0px;
}
.magic-container .menu-toggle {
   cursor:pointer;
}
.sidebar-shrink {
  height: 100%;
  width:180px;
  background: #000;
  padding: 0px;
}
.sidebar-shrink a {
   display:block;
   padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 17px;
   white-space:nowrap;
}
.sidebar-shrink ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid magic-container closed">
    <div class="col-md-2 sidebar-left-nav">
      <div class="sidebar-shrink">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Hello World<i class="pull-right  fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Hello World<i class="pull-right  fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 cont-main">
      <div>
        <h3 class="headline-primary">
         <i class="fa fa-bars pull-left menu-toggle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sidebar
          </h3>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Regards :)

Comment: thanks @jseezo, :), just a small question , will be possible after the click the sidebar-left-nav get removed from DOM? and main-content get width:100% ? as well if I click again the sidebar-left-nav back to the DOM? that is my last. :0 thank you

Comment: You're welcome @Reduken. Hmmm I can try but why You want to remove from DOM , you have to or You want ?? In my opinion , this code should be inside DOM , but i can try edit . Regards :)

Comment: if you could create a extra sample keeping the others will be fine, my problem is I am applying your code in another code :(, if I use just your code works perfect but when I apply in other code brakes everything, because is other classes and stuff understand? but I think just a jquery could help? on this? in my case I need remove the sidebar left from dom and include again and make the content 100% when the sidebar left is off and remove the 100% when is back. understand?

Comment: @Raduken I understand. Tomorrow I implement fix. Regards :)